# Why doesn't the .visible class work on tablets (iPad)?

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with using of **.visible-** class in **Boostrap 3.1.1.**

Here is a trivial code snippet:

```
<h3 class="visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">New User Registration</h3>
<h3 class="visible-xs">Registration</h3>
```

I am targeting on this behavior:

- on very small devices (such as phones) I would like to see text: "Registration" (longer text is wrapped)
- on other devices I would like to see text: "New User Registration" (there is enough space for this).

I have reached this result:

- on desktop I see "New User Registration" (OK)
- on phone (Samsung Galaxy SIII) I see "Registration" (OK)
- **on tablet (iPad4) is no text displayed (tested in Safari/Chrome)**

I have read some discussion about it and it seems, that Bootstrap 3.1.1 should be ready for this class mixing.

Please, could anyone help me?

Kind regards
Radek Budař

Comment: Hmm seems as though your code should work.. You could try using `hidden-xs` instead of `visible-lg visible-md visible-sm`

Comment: @subtletree is right. Your code works as-is : http://www.bootply.com/bwv2Ql1AxX. And his other suggestion works too, with less complexity: http://www.bootply.com/Aln0TFMkWz#.

Comment: It must be something else... can you include more code?

Comment: Code above is snippet from page, which is available on http://sandbox.budarovi.eu and after click on "Registrovat se" button top-right border of the page (sorry, it's not localized)